# structuremap does return named instance instead of default one

Tags: structuremap, named-instance

As the title says, structuremap does not return the default instance when i have also configured named instances.

Here is my type registration:

```
/// <summary>
  /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CommandProcessingTypeRegistry"/> class.
  /// </summary>
  public CommandProcessingTypeRegistry()
  {
     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<CommandCoordinator>();

     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<SystemCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(SystemCommandSwitch).FullName);
     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<TelephonyCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(TelephonyCommandSwitch).FullName);
     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<AudioCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(AudioCommandSwitch).FullName);
     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<TetraCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(TetraCommandSwitch).FullName);
     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<RadioCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(RadioCommandSwitch).FullName);
     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<SnapshotCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(SnapshotCommandSwitch).FullName);
     For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Use<TakeNextCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(TakeNextCommandSwitch).FullName);
  }
```

And this is how i request the instance:

```
_commandProcessor = _container.GetInstance<ICommandProcessor>(); // _container is the structuremap IContainer instance
```

I would like that the above line returns me the *CommandCoordinator* instance but instead the *TakeNextCommandSwitch* instance is returned.
What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Add instead of Use for the named instances:

```
For<ICommandProcessor>().Singleton().Add<TelephonyCommandSwitch>().Named(typeof(TelephonyCommandSwitch).FullName);
```